# Django: invalid certificate after installing SSLSERVER

Tags: python, django, ssl, certificate

I am trying to run my server with https, so I installed `django-sslserver`, and running as below.

```
py manage.py runsslserver --certificate F:/certs/server.crt --key F:/certs/server.key 127.0.0.1:8000
```

The output after execution is:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Validating models...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 22, 2021 - 23:20:11
Django version 3.1.2, using settings 'ecommerce.settings'
Starting development server at https://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using SSL certificate: F:/certs/server.crt
Using SSL key: F:/certs/server.key
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

The website is running well but I still get
[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Where do you have the certificate from? Self created?

Comment: yes, its self created. But even if i run ```python manage.py runsslserver``` without custom cert, i still get this problem

Comment: That's pretty much what you should expect. To get a trusted connection you need a certificate issued by a certificate authority that is trusted by your browser. They usually do not issue certificates for localhost. You can create an exception in the browser for self signed certificates.

Comment: Hmm cool. Do you suggest any tutorial or a post on how to do this?